# Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector not working for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have setup a dockerized cluster of Kafka Connect which is running in distributed mode.
I am trying to setup a Kafka JDBC Source Connector to move data between Microsoft SQL Server and Kafka.

Below is the output of the response of my `connector-plugins` api

```
[
    {
    class: "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    type: "sink",
    version: "4.0.0"
    },
    {
    class: "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    type: "sink",
    version: "4.0.0"
    },
    {
    class: "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector",
    type: "source",
    version: "1.0.0-cp1"
    },
    {
    class: "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    type: "sink",
    version: "4.0.0"
    },
    {
    class: "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    type: "source",
    version: "4.0.0"
    },
    {
    class: "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    type: "source",
    version: "0.7.4"
    },
    {
    class: "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    type: "source",
    version: "0.7.4"
    },
    {
    class: "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
    type: "sink",
    version: "1.0.0-cp1"
    },
    {
    class: "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    type: "source",
    version: "1.0.0-cp1"
    }
]
```

I have already added the `JDBC Driver provided my Microsoft SQL Server` to my `plugins path` in my Kafka Connect Cluster.

Below is the input to my `connectors` api,

```
curl -X POST \
  http://kafka-connect-cluster.com/connectors \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d '{
"name": "mssql-source-connector",
"config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "updateTimeStamp",
        "query": "select * from table_name",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "table.types": "TABLE",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "topic.prefix": "data_",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<dbName>;",
        "connection.user": "<username>",
        "connection.password": "<password>",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "poll.interval.ms": "5000",
        "table.poll.interval.ms": "120000"
    }
}'
```

The error that i get while trying this query is as follows:

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name>; for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name>;\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name;> for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name;>\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

Any help you can provide is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver to the classpath?

Comment: have you configured this connector (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector) a part  or  it was default ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit to the answer goes to @rmoff for pointing me in the right direction.

So the issue lied in two places.

1. This is more like an FYI, rather than an issue. I gave the docker image a custom `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH`. There is
   nothing wrong with doing that, but its generally not a good idea
   because you will have to copy all the base plugins available with
   the confluent platform, this can create a problem when move to a new
   version as you might have to go through the same process again.
2. This part is most important. The [SQLServer JDBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=jdbc) needs to
   be in the same folder as that of
   `kafka-connect-jdbc-<confluent-version>.jar` which in my case is
   `kafka-connect-jdbc-4.0.0.jar`.

Once these two points were addressed my SQLServer JDBC Driver started working as expected.

Comment: glad i could help @PrabuddhaKulatunga

Comment: In addition to this I also had to restart my connect docker container after dropping this file in. This is only relevant if you're running kafka connect in a container of course.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url the trailing `;` you have in the URL is not valid. 
Also try putting the JDBC driver in `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`, and/or adding it to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: you did point me in the right direction. The extra semi-colon is not really a problem. I guess the JDBC driver ignores it. The real problem was that i used the CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH to a custom directory, which didnt have all the jar's required. Once moving it back to `/usr/share/java` resolved the issue. Could you please update your answer to detail out the same, that will probably help others developers, i will mark it as the right answer after that.